# How to display anything into an array that changes based on user input?

Tags: java

Basically I have to make a random word search generator for my class, and I can get user input to create how many rows and how many columns the word search will have, and I can make my program ask the user to input x amount of words to find (based on rows) and the length of the words(based on columns) however for the life of me I can not find out how to print anything inside of this mysterious grid I have made. I just need to find out how to add random letters inside of the array/grid/board. Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment2 {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int[][] wordBoard;
    private char[][] gameBoard;
    private String[] wordList;
    private static int row;
    private static int col;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public void playWordSearch() {
        wordBoard = numRowCol();
        wordStorage(wordBoard);
    }

    /**
     * This method asks the user to input an integer for Rows/Columns
     * And gracefully handles invalid input :)
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int[][] numRowCol() {

        int array[] = new int[100];
        boolean again = true;

        while (again) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                try {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        System.out.printf("Enter a number of rows (2-15): %n");
                        array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (array[i] > 15 || array[i] < 2) {
                            System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                            i -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                    i -= 1;
                    keyboard.next();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.printf("Enter a number of columns (2-15): %n");
                        array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (array[i] > 15 || array[i] < 2) {
                            System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                            i -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                    i -= 1;
                    keyboard.next();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            again = false;
        }
        System.out.printf("The amount of rows you have entered: %d%nAnd the amount of columns: %d%n", array[0], array[1]);
        int[][] arrayArray = new int[array[0]][array[1]];
        return arrayArray;
    }

    public int wordStorage(int[][] arrayArray) {
        int size;
        String word[] = new String[arrayArray.length];
        int sizeRow = arrayArray.length;
        int sizeCol = arrayArray[1].length;

        System.out.printf("rows: %d%n", sizeRow);
        System.out.printf("cols: %d%n", sizeCol);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter a word with less than %d characters: %n", sizeCol);
            word[i] = keyboard.next();
        }
        keyboard.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayArray).replace("], ",
                "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output? You ask for the number of columns but then you ask to enter a word with less than the number of columns. Why? Shouldn't you be asking for word with exactly the number of columns?

Comment: yeah, poor grammar in the code. The output *should* have every word you entered and fill the empty spaces with random letters. Which I am trying to do now. Thanks

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Assignment2 {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private char[][] wordBoard;
    private char[][] gameBoard;
    private String[] wordList;
    private static int row;
    private static int col;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public void playWordSearch() {
        wordBoard = numRowCol();
        wordStorage(wordBoard);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.playWordSearch();


    }

    /**
     * This method asks the user to input an integer for Rows/Columns
     * And gracefully handles invalid input :)
     *
     * @return
     */
    public char[][] numRowCol() {

        int array[] = new int[100];
        boolean again = true;

        while (again) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                try {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        System.out.printf("Enter a number of rows (2-15): %n");
                        array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (array[i] > 15 || array[i] < 2) {
                            System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                            i -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                    i -= 1;
                    keyboard.next();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        System.out.printf("Enter a number of columns (2-15): %n");
                        array[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
                        if (array[i] > 15 || array[i] < 2) {
                            System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                            i -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.printf("Requirements: int between [2-15] %n");
                    i -= 1;
                    keyboard.next();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            again = false;
        }
        System.out.printf("The amount of rows you have entered: %d%nAnd the amount of columns: %d%n", array[0], array[1]);
        char[][] arrayArray = new char[array[0]][array[1]];
        return arrayArray;
    }

    public int wordStorage(char[][] arrayArray) {
        int size;
        String word[] = new String[arrayArray.length];
        int sizeRow = arrayArray.length;
        int sizeCol = arrayArray[1].length;

        System.out.printf("rows: %d%n", sizeRow);
        System.out.printf("cols: %d%n", sizeCol);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter a word with less than %d characters: %n", sizeCol);
            word[i] = keyboard.next();
        }
        keyboard.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; ++i) {
            arrayArray[i] = word[i].toCharArray();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayArray).replace("], ",
            "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));
        return 100;
    }
}
```

First, your grid was a 2d *int* array not a 2d *char* array for your words (your functions also returned a 2d int array instead of a 2d char array). Second, I just added a simple for loop to assign user input of words into the array.

If you need to fill the empty spaces from the columns, simply generate random char values, fill the char arrays to meet the size values, then assign them into the array like I did above.